# What does DLRS Mean as the 4th Most Common Word in ~10,000 News Articles?

Tags: meaning, acronyms, journalism

I just conducted a frequency distribution of ~10,000 news articles and removing punctuation and stop words (common words like "the", "a", "an", etc.) I Found that the top word after "said", "man", and "vs" is "dlrs." I assume this is an acronym for something but when I Google it all I get it some licensing agency in Maine and some security print group in Ireland. I presume that the nearly 12,000 occurrences of this doesn't refer to either of those, **so what could DLRS mean in the context of news many news articles from ~2000-2010?** I'm sorry if I'm at the wrong place.

Comment: Dollars? Dealers? Technically, it's not a word, so I recommend adding it to your ignore list.

Comment: Oh ya it probably means dollars.

Comment: Dlrs is not an abbreviation for dollars in the US, where we show dollars with a dollar sign ($) before numbers, and write the word out in other contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite impossible to know what *dlrs* refers to without seeing the source material, as there is no single meaning that stands out from any other.

Some uses probably represent *dollars*, as per [Random House Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dlrs-); others could be [various intialisms](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/DLRS) per AcronymFinder.com; it could be an obvious typo, such as for *DSLR*, or a more obscure one— on an English QWERTY keyboard, the letters *dlrs* are very close to those for *does*, which one would expect to be very common.

Comment: Thank you for the response and I do think that in nearly every case it means dollars (although I've never seen the acronym). I doubt that in published articles there would be no more than a handful of typos of the word _"does"_ that would get _3_ letter wrong especially considering nearly 10,000 articles. I am just rather surprised that it is such a common acronym (it occurs roughly 1.2 times per article in this set of articles) and yet I have never seen it. Maybe it quickly feel out of favor. I am young but still I read quite a bit of the news.

Comment: @DylanSiegler Just because a collection has 10,000 articles does not necessarily mean it is representative of all English. Where did those articles appear? What dialects do the writers and editors speak? What about the intended readers? When were the articles published? If it's 10,000 articles from Gibraltarian financial newspapers, it's a different corpus from 10,000 articles from Filipino entertainment websites.

Comment: They were all American or British English news articles of assorted (mostly finance related) topics.